# collection_select NoMethodError - noticed after switching to rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

After updating to rails 3.2.11, I noticed a problem with a search form in my app.  After seeing the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message on Heroku, I checked the logs and noticed the error message below:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for ["2010"]:Array):
app/controllers/skis_controller.rb:29:in `index'
```

This is referring to the index controller, where my search results are displayed.  Im using a search form partial for the actual search form, which contains several collection_selects.

Line 29 in the index action refers to the model_year ("2010" in the search above).  When I remove the model_year field from the collection_select everything works fine (no error message after searching).  This is what the model_year collection_select looks like:

```
<%= collection_select(:ski, :model_year, @model_years.sort_by(&:model_year).reverse, :model_year, :model_year, {}, :multiple => true, :class => "chzn-select", :'data-placeholder' => "Enter Model Year") %>
```

This is bugging me because it has been working fine for the last three weeks.  I recently updated to rails 3.2.11 but I'm not positive that is when the problem started (I know I did not notice it before).  I checked out the collection_select documentation and everything seems fine.

model_year is stored in the database as an integer and I've confirmed this with rails console.

Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated!  Thanks

EDIT - UPDATED to add controller code:

```
def index

  @companies = Brand.scoped
  @ski_types = Ski.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT ski_type")
  @genders = Ski.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT gender")
  @names = Ski.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT name")
  @price_ranges = PriceRange.scoped
  @model_years = Ski.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT model_year")
  @sorts = ["Price", "Rating", "Availability"]

if params[:ski].present? || params[:brand].present? || params[:price_range].present?
# Creates references for collection select

  ski_type = params[:ski][:ski_type].reject(&:blank?)
  gender = params[:ski][:gender].reject(&:blank?)
  company = params[:brand][:company].reject(&:blank?)
  name = params[:ski][:name].reject(&:blank?)
  price_range = params[:price_range][:price_range]
  model_year = params[:ski][:model_year].reject(&:blank?)
  # raise ski_type.any?.inspect

  @ski = Ski.new
  @ski.ski_type = ski_type
  @ski.gender = gender
  @ski.name = name
  @ski.model_year = model_year

  @price_range = PriceRange.new
  @price_range.price_range = price_range

  @brand = Brand.new
  @brand.company = company

  skis = Inventory.search_price(price_range)

  skis_refined = Ski.search_characteristics(ski_type, gender, company, name, model_year)

  ski_ids2 = skis.map(&:id) & skis_refined.map(&:id)

  @all_skis = Ski.where(:id => ski_ids2)

  if params[:sort_by] == "Price Low to High"
    @overlapping_skis = Kaminari.paginate_array(@all_skis.joins(:inventories).order("inventories.price ASC").uniq_by(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per(30)
  elsif params[:sort_by] == "Price High to Low"
    @overlapping_skis = Kaminari.paginate_array(@all_skis.joins(:inventories).order("inventories.price DESC").uniq_by(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per(30)
  elsif params[:sort_by] == "Rating"
    @overlapping_skis = Kaminari.paginate_array(@all_skis.joins(:reviews).order("reviews.average_review DESC").uniq_by(&:id)).page(params[:page]).per(30)
  else
    @overlapping_skis = @all_skis.joins(:brand).order("brands.company ASC, skis.model_year DESC, skis.name ASC").page(params[:page])
  end

else
  @overlapping_skis = Ski.joins(:brand).order("brands.company ASC, skis.model_year DESC, skis.name ASC").page(params[:page])
end


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @skis }
end
end
```

Updated for search method:

```
def self.search_characteristics(ski_type, gender, company, name, model_year)
@skis = Ski.scoped
if ski_type.any?
    @skis = @skis.where(:ski_type => ski_type)
end
if gender.any?
  @skis = @skis.where(:gender => gender)
end
if company.any?
  brand_object = Brand.where(:company => company)

  @id_array = brand_object.map(&:id)

  @skis = @skis.where(:brand_id => @id_array)
end
if name.any?
  @skis = @skis.where(:name => name)
end
if model_year.any?
  @skis = @skis.where(:model_year => model_year)
end
return @skis
 end
```

Comment: Which line in the controller is line 29?

Comment: Sorry I missed your question earlier - it is @ski.model_year = model_year

Answer (score 0):

You have `:multiple => true`, meaning there can be multiple selected values for model_year, which is why it's an array. You'll have to handle those multiple values some way or remove `:multiple => true`.

Comment: Correct - a user needs to have the ability to enter multiple years.  It was working fine before with multiple=>true and continues to work for the other collection_selects in the search form, which also have multiple=>true.  Any idea where the to_i is coming in (part of the collection_select or sort_by?)?  Not even sure where to_i is being called on that array.

Comment: Are you using another gem or something to implement search?

Comment: Wrote a simple search method stored in the model.  It is basically performing "where" lookups for attributes to give the index view a revised set of inventory.

Comment: Added the relevant controller and search method code - I know I have a lot of refactoring to do!